Media endpoint of Instagram graph API not working
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/{ig-media-id}
  ?fields={fields}
  &access_token={access-token}

It shows:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17895695668004550' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "A-IeuyxJqCPecIYZwWkiY0y"
  }
}

The ig-media-id is from Instagram official documentation. Its saying same with all other ids.
I have even allowed all permission to tackle permission missing.
I was expecting response from api with all those data but instead getting that error

You don't get access to just any arbitrary media objects, only those your user has administrative access to.
